# CSS font-face loads into app ~50% of the time, why is it skipping?

Tags: css, font-face

This is the code in the CSS file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Interstate-RegularRegular';
    src: url('../../_model/ui_assets/fonts/interstate-regular-webfont.eot?#IEFix');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Whenever the web app is executed, the page will show the correct font (Interstate-Regular) about half the time. The rest of the time, the page will default to Arial I believe. This app will be designed for IE8 use. As you can see, I am pointing to a .EOT file. I cannot understand why there is an 'occasional' failure - there is no identifiable pattern here. Has anyone else experienced something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the style on load or applying it in jquery/javascript after the DOM has loaded?  This sounds like it could be a timing issue?

Comment: The style is being used on load

Comment: Try applying the class to your elements after load in a js at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Are you suggesting I put the js in the css file or the html?

Comment: in the html file down at the bottom before the closing body tag.  This will give the font a chance to download before you apply it.